# Sidebar surrounded with tiles

Tags: html, css

I need a solution to achieve the following result:

[image: template idea]

The sidebar should be surrounded by dynamically added tiles.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you..

Comment: Stupid me ... got the solution XD display:grid with grid-area did the trick :D